# python regex repeat "'s"?

Tags: python, regex

How to repeat "'s" (2 charaters)
I used '\b\'s\b*' but I got error: nothing to repeat

Comment: Your question is unclear, please explain more.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Did you mean `r'(\'s)+'`? Please explain more clearly next time.